# WP : cannot retrieve the excerpts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get excerpts without WP.

```
<?php
require('../blog/wp-load.php');
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts'=>'1',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','excerpt') )
);
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]; // ok
    echo $recent["post_title"]; // ok
    $echo wp_trim_excerpt( $recent['post_content']); // BAD: gives FULL article and not 55 words
    echo $recent->post_excerpt; // BAD: gives EMPTY String
    echo get_the_excerpt($recent); // BAD: gives EMPTY String
}
```

All approches are giving me bad result.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $recent['post_excerpt'];` instead of `echo $recent->post_excerpt;`? It's probably an associative array, not an object (since you get other values with array keys without errors). If it doesn't help, try `get_the_excerpt($recent['ID']);`

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use setup_postdata() to setup global post data.

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    setup_postdata( $recent );
    echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]; // ok
    echo $recent["post_title"]; // ok
    echo get_the_excerpt($recent); 
}
```

Functions like get_the_excerpt() behaves differently when used outside the main loop.

Read about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/).

> If this function is used outside The Loop and the post doesn’t have a custom excerpt, this function will use wp_trim_excerpt() to generate an excerpt. That function uses get_the_content(), which must be used with The Loop and will cause problems if get_the_excerpt() is being used outside The Loop. In order to avoid the issues, use setup_postdata() prior to calling get_the_excerpt() to set up the global $post object.

Comment: this will probably work right now, but for full API compliance you should only call `setup_postdata()` using the global `$post` object (which you can set), and once you are done you should call `wp_reset_postdata()`.